# query reports one per week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a stored procedure which make sum of column prod in table for each week from column data.

Can anyone help me?

```
select sum (prod) from table
```

for each week group by week

```
data           prod
2018-08-24  1,2
2018-08-25  2,37
2018-08-25  2,3
2018-08-25  2,04
2018-08-25  2,8
2018-08-25  1,85
2018-08-25  3,1
2018-08-26  1,72
2018-08-26  2,7
2018-08-31  5,5
2018-09-01  2,62
2018-09-01  2,4
2018-09-01  1,55
2018-09-01  1,61
2018-09-01  2,37
2018-09-01  11
2018-09-02  1,4
2018-09-02  1,75
2018-09-14  1,4
2018-09-15  1,2
2018-09-15  4
2018-09-15  2,54
2018-09-15  2,37
2018-09-15  1,53
2018-09-15  2,1
2018-09-16  2,62
2018-09-16  1,66
2018-09-21  1,72
2018-09-22  2,5
2018-09-22  2,37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use DATEPART:

```
select YEAR(data), DATEPART(ww, data ), sum (prod) 
from table
group by YEAR(data), DATEPART(ww, data )
```

Comment: ok but if i wont make raport for each week but it start on Wednesday to Tuesday

Comment: then add offset to date column: `DATEPART(ww, data+2 )`

Comment: @MatR You need to adjust it to your need the offset is from 1-6

Comment: yes i know but "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

Comment: @Tom `DATEPART(ww, DATEADD(d, <offset>, data))`